# same mysql query taking too long in mysql than mariadb

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I migrated from MariaDB to Mysql. My query below is taking more than three minutes in Mysql, but less than one minute in MariaDB. Mysql version is 5.7. 
Please suggest how can I deal with this problem, thanks a lot!!!

```
SELECT 
COUNT(*)
FROM
(SELECT i.*, f.*, c.*, ft.*, -- summarized for readability
        (SELECT f1.id
         FROM sys_exten_flow_task f1
         WHERE f1.instance_id = f.INSTANCE_ID AND state = '1'
         ORDER BY f1.update_date DESC
         LIMIT 0 , 1) AS pretaskid,
        CASE
            WHEN i.FLOW_DEFINE IS NULL THEN 'free'
            ELSE i.FLOW_DEFINE
        END AS fd,
        CASE
            WHEN f.TASK_DEFINE_ID IS NULL THEN 'free'
            ELSE f.TASK_DEFINE_ID
        END AS tdi
FROM
    sys_exten_flow_task f, sys_exten_flow_instance i,
    sys_exten_flow_define_task dt, sys_user c, sys_dict ft
WHERE
    i.ID = f.INSTANCE_ID
        AND i.CREATE_BY = c.ID
        AND i.FLOW_TYPE = ft.ID
        AND dt.id = f.task_define_id) a;

+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  3841309 |
+----------+
1 row in set (3 min 21.97 sec)
```

with the explain plan

```
+----+--------------------+------------+------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------+------------------------+---------+----------------------------+---------+----------+---------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table      | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                    | key                    | key_len | ref                        | rows    | filtered | Extra                                 |
+----+--------------------+------------+------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------+------------------------+---------+----------------------------+---------+----------+---------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | <derived2> | NULL       | ALL    | NULL                                             | NULL                   | NULL    | NULL                       | 3640604 |   100.00 | NULL                                  |
|  2 | DERIVED            | i          | NULL       | ALL    | PRIMARY,CREATE_BY                                | NULL                   | NULL    | NULL                       |  788059 |   100.00 | Using where                           |
|  2 | DERIVED            | ft         | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,ID                                       | PRIMARY                | 258     | scdxoa.i.FLOW_TYPE         |       1 |   100.00 | Using where                           |
|  2 | DERIVED            | c          | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,ID                                       | PRIMARY                | 258     | scdxoa.i.CREATE_BY         |       1 |   100.00 | NULL                                  |
|  2 | DERIVED            | f          | NULL       | ref    | INDEX_TASK_INSTANCE_ID,INDEX_TASK_TASK_DEFINE_ID | INDEX_TASK_INSTANCE_ID | 402     | scdxoa.i.ID                |       4 |   100.00 | Using index condition; Using where    |
|  2 | DERIVED            | dt         | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                          | PRIMARY                | 258     | scdxoa.f.TASK_DEFINE_ID    |       1 |   100.00 | Using where                           |
|  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | f1         | NULL       | ref    | INDEX_TASK_STATUS,INDEX_TASK_INSTANCE_ID,INDEX   | INDEX                  | 408     | const,scdxoa.f.INSTANCE_ID |       3 |   100.00 | Using index condition; Using filesort |
+----+--------------------+------------+------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------+------------------------+---------+----------------------------+---------+----------+---------------------------------------+

7 rows in set, 2 warnings (0.01 sec)
```

Executing the same query in MariaDB, I get

```
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  3912445 |
+----------+
1 row in set (56.54 sec)
```

with the explain plan

```
+------+--------------------+-------+--------+--------------------------------------------------+------------------------+---------+-------------------------+-------+----------+------------------------------------+

| id   | select_type        | table | type   | possible_keys                                    | key                    | key_len | ref                     | rows  | filtered | Extra                              |
+------+--------------------+-------+--------+--------------------------------------------------+------------------------+---------+-------------------------+-------+----------+------------------------------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY            | c     | index  | PRIMARY,ID                                       | group_login_name       | 205     | NULL                    | 23047 |   100.00 | Using index                        |
|    1 | PRIMARY            | i     | ref    | PRIMARY,CREATE_BY                                | CREATE_BY              | 259     | scdxoa.c.ID             |    15 |   100.00 |                                    |
|    1 | PRIMARY            | ft    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,ID                                       | PRIMARY                | 258     | scdxoa.i.FLOW_TYPE      |     1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index           |
|    1 | PRIMARY            | f     | ref    | INDEX_TASK_INSTANCE_ID,INDEX_TASK_TASK_DEFINE_ID | INDEX_TASK_INSTANCE_ID | 402     | scdxoa.i.ID             |     2 |   100.00 | Using index condition; Using where |
|    1 | PRIMARY            | dt    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                          | PRIMARY                | 258     | scdxoa.f.TASK_DEFINE_ID |     1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index           |
|    3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | f1    | ref    | INDEX_TASK_STATUS,INDEX_TASK_INSTANCE_ID,INDEX   | INDEX_TASK_INSTANCE_ID | 402     | scdxoa.f.INSTANCE_ID    |     2 |   100.00 | Using where; Using filesort        |
+------+--------------------+-------+--------+--------------------------------------------------+------------------------+---------+-------------------------+-------+----------+------------------------------------+

6 rows in set, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

I also try to let Mysql to execute the result sql from mariadb optimized.

```
select count(0) AS "count(*)" 
from "scdxoa"."sys_exten_flow_task" "f" 
join "scdxoa"."sys_exten_flow_instance" "i" 
join "scdxoa"."sys_exten_flow_define_task" "dt" 
join "scdxoa"."sys_user" "c" 
join "scdxoa"."sys_dict" "ft" 
where (("scdxoa"."i"."CREATE_BY" = "scdxoa"."c"."ID") 
     and ("scdxoa"."i"."ID" = "scdxoa"."f"."INSTANCE_ID") 
     and ("scdxoa"."i"."FLOW_TYPE" = "scdxoa"."ft"."ID") 
     and ("scdxoa"."dt"."ID" = "scdxoa"."f"."TASK_DEFINE_ID"));
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  3841309 |
+----------+
1 row in set (21.83 sec)
```

Comment: Please provide the explain plan for mariadb too (both preferably as text, not as an image). And please match your explain plan to your query. If you do not think it is important to add the explain plan for all the unions (which I think is a correct assessment if that part alone takes 3 minutes), you do not need to present the complete query in your query, just the part that takes that long.

Comment: Do you know about mysql indexes? If  your mariadb database has indexed tables and your mysql database has not, this could massively slow down your queries. You can easily solve this by adding indexes to your new db.

Comment: @ Solarflare thank you.I have updated my question like you say,I also post the mariadb explain result and part sql  taking too long time ,rather than a complete sql

Comment: @ Benni I also try to let Mysql to execute the result sql  mariadb optimized. the performance is ok,so I guess there is not the  indexes problem.

Comment: @supergang I edited your question to make it more readable, please check if I misinterpreted something. MySQL is slower here because it materialized your subquery (which uses resources), while MariaDB didn't (and it should not do it actually - you may want to specify your complete MySQL version, MySQL 5.7 spans 5 years over various versions). You can see the effect of not doing unncessary things (materializing, the `pretaskid` subquery, ...) in the "optimized" version, so just use this format. Your original query used `union all`, so you can just add several of those counts.

Comment: What are the "2 warnings"?  (`SHOW WARNINGS;` just after doing the `EXPLAIN`.)

Answer (score 0):

Some amount of time is wasted by this construct:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM ( SELECT lots-of-columns
               FROM, etc )
```

Instead of simply

```
           SELECT COUNT(*)
               FROM, etc
```

This is because the derived table is built and put into a temp table, probably on disk in your case, then counted.

Since I don't see a "2" in MariaDB's `EXPLAIN`, I *guess* that they did that Optimization for you.

At 5.6 and 10.0, they made some noticeable divergences in their Optimizers. You hit a case where MariaDB shines.

Simplify the first `CASE..END` to `IFNULL(i.FLOW_DEFINE, 'free')`; etc.

Please use `JOIN..ON` instead of comma+WHERE -- This won't help speed, but may help readability.

Even within the subquery there are other simplifications; for example, the CASEs provide nothing toward the COUNT. Whether or not you care, you might more help from us if you provide a minimal test case that demonstrates the problem.